# How do I get my java ArrayList to display properly?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a class where a user inputs information about an employee (first and last name, address, hire date) for a user determined number of employees.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Employee {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String employeeName = null;
        String employeeAddress = null;
        String hireDate = null;

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many employees would you like to enter information for?");
        int numEmployees = userInput.nextInt();

        for( int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter employees first name: ");
            String firstName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter employees last name: ");
            String lastName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter street employee lives on:");
            String street = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter city employee lives in:");
            String city = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter state employee lives in:");
            String state = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter employee's zip code:");
            String zip = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter month employee was hired:");
            String month = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter day employee was hired:");
            String day = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter year employee was hired:");
            String year = input.nextLine();

            Name name = new Name(firstName, lastName);
            Address address = new Address(street, city, state, zip);
            Date date = new Date(month, day, year);

            employeeName = name.getName();
            employeeAddress = address.getAddress();
            hireDate = date.getDate();

            ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
            obj.add(employeeName);
            obj.add(employeeAddress);
            obj.add(hireDate);
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the program to go through the user prompts, take that info and put it in a position in an ArrayList, then repeat for however many times the user determined earlier and display all at once at the end. Something like this:

```
FirstName LastName, Address, Hire Date
FirstName LastName, Address, Hire Date
```

And so on. Right now, my code will run through the user prompts, display that, then run through the next round of prompts and display that:

```
Enter Name:
 Name
Enter Address:
 Address
Enter Hire Date:
 Hire Date

[Name, Address, Hire Date]

Enter Name:
 Name
Enter Address:
 Address
Enter Hire Date:
 Hire Date

[Name, Address, Hire Date]
```

I realize this is because my array and array display are within the for loop, but when I move the array outside the loop I get no display. When I move just the array display outside the loop, my code doesn't compile.

Comment: Not related to your question, but make sure to `input.close()` to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @AMACB or try-with-resources. Looks like it implements Closeable interface.

Comment: @AMACB Would this be why I'm getting this error when debugging?
Error:(63, 2) java: reached end of file while parsing

Comment: @Jes That means you are missing a `}` at the end of your code (add it in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this line:

```
System.out.println(obj);
```

out of the `for` loop. And use `List` to contain the `ArrayList`. Then you display it in a separate `for` loop:

```
List<ArrayList<String>> objs = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); //use list of objs
for( int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++ )
{
    //all the inputs

    ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
    obj.add(employeeName);
    obj.add(employeeAddress);
    obj.add(hireDate);
    objs.add(obj);

}

for( int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++ ) //for loop just to display
    System.out.println(objs.get(i)); //display each element here
```

Comment: When you say "all the inputs" do you mean my employeeName, employeeAddress, and hireDate variables?

Comment: @Jes it basically means, all that you have typed in, except on the lines when `ArrayList` is declared and below. :)

Comment: Oh, I see. It isn't a new loop with that code. You're representing my already existing for loop with all the long crazy stuff cut out.

Comment: @Jes yes, you got it right. I cut all the above parts to highlight what you need to change...

Comment: When i run this through the debugger it it displays the name and address of the first entry, but not the hire date or any of the subsequent employee's info

Comment: I get: Error:(18, 40) java: java.util.List is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Comment: @Jes OK, another thing which I forgot, pardon me again. `Java` `List` must be instantiated as as non-abstract, try to use `ArrayList` to instantiate, I will update my answer.

Comment: @Jes OK, answer updated. Anyway, you can also use `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` if you want. :)

Comment: Perfect! Much appreciated!

Comment: @Jes glad that it helps you. :) sorry about the earlier mistakes though... I did not notice it since I did not use my `Eclipse`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are printing out is a tuple of type [string, string, string].  This can be represented as a List.  Then for each employee you want to store this tuple in another List of type `List<List<String>>`.

```
public static void main( String [] args )
{

    String employeeName = null;
    String employeeAddress = null;
    String hireDate = null;

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many employees would you like to enter information for?");
    int numEmployees = userInput.nextInt();
    List<List<String>> employesInfo = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    for( int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++ )
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter employees first name: ");
        String firstName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter employees last name: ");
        String lastName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter street employee lives on:");
        String street = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter city employee lives in:");
        String city = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter state employee lives in:");
        String state = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter employee's zip code:");
        String zip = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter month employee was hired:");
        String month = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter day employee was hired:");
        String day = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter year employee was hired:");
        String year = input.nextLine();

        Name name = new Name(firstName, lastName);
        Address address = new Address(street, city, state, zip);
        Date date = new Date(month, day, year);

        employeeName = name.getName();
        employeeAddress = address.getAddress();
        hireDate = date.getDate();

        ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
        obj.add(employeeName);
        obj.add(employeeAddress);
        obj.add(hireDate);

        employeesInfo.add(obj);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++ ) {
        System.out.println(emploeesInfo.get(i));
    }
}
```